# Discord.js token login issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, token, bots, discord.js

*Hi, my bot won't go online, even if I regenerate the token. I tried to put a catch block but nothing changes. Is the problem my computer ?the script ? or my node version(last LTS one) ? I hope that you will have the time to answer me !*

**Here's the error :**

```
    (node:1976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Atelier34bc\Documents\mpbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientManager.js:48:41)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at WebSocketConnection.onClose (C:\Users\Atelier34bc\Documents\mpbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:390:10)
    at WebSocket.onClose (C:\Users\Atelier34bc\Documents\mpbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:124:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at WebSocket.emitClose (C:\Users\Atelier34bc\Documents\mpbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:191:10)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnClose (C:\Users\Atelier34bc\Documents\mpbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:850:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at net.js:672:12
(node:1976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:1976) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Here's my script :**

```
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const PREFIX = "$"
const token = 'my_token'
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is online')
})

bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {

        case 'mpall':
            if (message.author.id == 655346300958670848) {
                const embeds = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setColor('#FF0000')
                    .setTitle('Message :')
                    .setDescription(args.slice(1).join(" "))
                message.guild.members.forEach(member =>
                    member.sendEmbed(embeds))
                break;               
            } else {
                var embeds1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setColor('#FF0000')
                    .setTitle('Acess Denied')
                message.channel.send(embeds1)
            }

            break;
    }
})
```

bot.login(token);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code with my own bot and it worked fine, have you checked that you are using the bot token instead of client id?

Comment: It s the token, I ve checked rn.Anyways, I m happy to hear that it works with your bot, the script is not the problem. What version of node js and discord js do you have ? I ll try with your versions and see if the problem is node or discord js. Thanks you for your answer ; )

Comment: my node.js version is v12.13.0 and my discord.js version is 11.5.1 . I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much, I ve restarted my computer and it worked. I know it s kinda weird